# How to distinguish user edits from data model updates with Qt widgets?

Tags: qt, model-view-controller

I'm trying to implement MVC in Qt using a data model ported from another platform. I have several widgets onscreen that each listen to the same model to render the data. The user can also interact with these widgets, edit them, and thus push changes back into the model.

The specific problem I have is that if my (ported) data model changes and I push data into eg a QTreeWidgetItem with setData, the widget emits an itemChanged signal.  This in turn triggers the controller code that is monitoring user edits, and causes it to push the same data back to the model. Unless I insert data comparison somewhere, I end up with an infinite loop.

Is there some way for the controller to quietly update the item's data without emitting itemChanged? Alternately, is there a better way to distinguish between user edits on a widget and programmatic changes?  I am simply listening for itemChanged.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some way for the controller to quietly update the item's data
>   without emitting itemChanged?

I hope not. I would not like it if I had a view, which shows wrong data because someone secretly changed the model. I am afraid, you have to conjure up something yourself. You have to modify your controller. Not emitting itemChanged when it does.... horrible idea.

I was thinking, what you could do. Expect no complete solution. I just looked around how I would do it. You must subblass your model and override the setData method. Then you can distinguish changes by the role. Qt::EditRole or you can create your own user defined role. The itemChanged signal must be emitted in any case. Else your views would be wrong. But in your model subclass you could implement a new signal 'dataChangedByUser' or whatever, which could be emitted additionally to itemChanged. How your controller handles this....

Comment: I see your point but in that case is there no way to distinguish user updates to the view from updates that are bubbling up from the model? It seems that itemChanged is the only signal emitted in both cases, which doesn't help.

Comment: I am not sure. Sometimes I still get surprised by Qt. And I don't know every single function in every class. But I think it is **very** unlikely that such a function or signal exists. It would make a somewhat dirty api. Changing data is changing data from the model's point of view. How or why the data changes... not its concern. You must do something in your controller. You know when a user changes the data. You must handle the different context.